# Finding the mean and variance of new random variable, from three existing random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value, standard-deviation

If R is the new random variable, derived from original random variable X, altered by two other random variables X and Y in the form of

$$\ R = \sqrt{(X + A)^2 + B^2} $$

X is a normal random variable with mean and SD of m1 and s1. 
A and B are also normal random variables with mean of zero and SD of s2 and s3 respectively. X, A and B are independent of each other.

What is the expected mean and SD of R?

I tried, but could not find a way where to start. Any hints for how to approach this problem would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Are they independent? For example the mean of $(X+A)^2$ depends on the correlation between $X$ and $A$.

Comment: How is $X$ distributed?

Comment: X, A and B are all independent of each other. X is normally distributed (it was a typo in the question, which I have edited now).